# TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' objects are immutable python

Tags: python, flask

Hi I'm trying to add a new key value pair but I'm receiving an error of 
**TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' objects are immutable** the variable I'm trying to add a new key came from a **request.form** but I can't add a new key value. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Here is my code on my controller

```
@benefits_api.route("/templates", methods=["POST"])
def store():

    parameters = request.form
    response = BenefitTemplateService.create(parameters)

    return jsonify(response), response['code']
```

and my service is like this

```
class BenefitTemplateService(object):

    @staticmethod
    def create(params):
        # some validation here

        params['credit_behavior'] = "none"
        return params
```

But I'm getting an error on the assignment for credit_behavior below is the error message

[image]

Comment: Try to transform `ImmutableMultiDict` to `dict`. And then modify it.

Comment: Yeah I tried it and it works. I'm just not sure why I can't directly modify the request.form to add a new value. Maybe its an object and not a dict

Comment: The exception information is said `request.form` is a `ImmutableMultiDict`. Immutable means it can't be modify like `tuple`.

Comment: `Immutable` variables cannot be changed.

Comment: Just replace the old form with the new one if it's an instance of immutable dict. Or create a dict with the new values, then create a new ImmutableDict from that and set that as the new property

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the builtin `to_dict()` method of `ImmutableMultiDict`, this will provide you with a dict you can freely modify.

You could for example make the following change to your code:

```
@benefits_api.route("/templates", methods=["POST"])
def store():

    parameters = request.form.to_dict()
    response = BenefitTemplateService.create(parameters)

    return jsonify(response), response['code']
```